# "unknown column X.id" error in django using existing DB

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a model for an existsing DB. Using the output of `manage.py inspectdb`, My `models.py` file looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

...some more stuff here...

class Scripts(models.Model):
    run_site = models.ForeignKey(Sites, db_column='run_site')
    script_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    module_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=120)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(QAPeople, db_column='owner')
    only_server = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    guest = models.IntegerField()
    registered = models.IntegerField()
    super = models.IntegerField()
    admin = models.IntegerField()
    run_timing = models.CharField(max_length=27)
    manual_owner = models.ForeignKey(QAPeople, db_column='manual_owner')
    script_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True,)
    version = models.IntegerField()
    comment = models.ForeignKey('ScriptComments', null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'scripts'
```

When I try to do `Scripts.objects.all()` I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 68, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 83, in __len__
    self._result_cache.extend(list(self._iter))
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 269, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 672, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 727, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", line 15, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 86, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 173, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'scripts.id' in 'field list'")
```

Why does django think there should be a `scripts.id` column? How do I fix it *without* dropping the tables etc?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is always by default an [implicit `id` field as auto incrementing primary key](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) on every model. See [primary_key in the Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#primary-key) how to change that field to some other name, but there needs to be one primary key (also in your table).

Also you may not want to call one of your fields `super`, since it is shadowing Python's built-in `super` in the class body. Might give you a hard time finding a bug some day.

Comment: This is why it's a good habit to use `model.pk` to refer to the primary key rather than `model.id`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you'r familiar with [django-south?](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/)

It's a nice little tool that helps you migrate your data from one structure to another and also helps identify issues before commiting info to the table, causing less errors and debugging afterwards.