# django adding query for id

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

My call is

```
venues = ExtCalendar.objects.all()
```

but I get an error

```
(1054, "Unknown column 'ext_calendar.id' in 'field list'")
```

Even though the ext_calendar table does not have this column

My model:

```
class ExtCalendar(models.Model):
    source_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ext_type = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    ext_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    out_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    confidence = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=8192, blank=True, null=True)
    ext_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    out_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_out_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    out_formatted = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
    ext_formatted = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ext_calendar'
        unique_together = (('source_id', 'ext_type', 'ext_id'),)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ext_id
```

The return value of `venues` is a QuerySet containing an incorrect query of:

```
SELECT `ext_calendar`.`id`, `ext_calendar`.`source_id`, `ext_calendar`.`ext_type`, `ext_calendar`.`ext_id`, `ext_calendar`.`out_id`, `ext_calendar`.`confidence`, `ext_calendar`.`data`, `ext_calendar`.`ext_name`, `ext_calendar`.`out_name`, `ext_calendar`.`last_out_id`, `ext_calendar`.`status`, `ext_calendar`.`out_formatted`, `ext_calendar`.`ext_formatted` FROM `ext_calendar`
```

So how do I remove id from the query?

Comment: Have you seen these SO questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192409/unknown-column-x-id-error-in-django-using-existing-db and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787237/django-models-1054-unknown-column-in-field-list

Comment: Ah, I do not have a sync issue, but one of the answers  there did link to what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: actually, i didn't that first link, yes this question is dup of that one

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Buried deep in the docs,

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

django automatically (and silently) add the id field for you.
From the docs:

> ## Automatic primary key fields
>
> By default, Django gives each model the following field:
>
> `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`
>
> This is an auto-incrementing primary key.
>
> If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, just specify **primary_key=True** on one of your fields. If Django sees you’ve explicitly set **Field.primary_key**, it won’t add the automatic **id** column.
>
> Each model requires exactly one field to have **primary_key=True** (either explicitly declared or automatically added).

Comment: If the wuestion is a self admitted duplicate, then pls fo not answer it, but either remove it or wait until it is marked as duplicate and then accept it.

Comment: answered before i realized it was a dup