# Unknown column 'ModelName.id' in 'field list'"

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Django with mysql. I have created `models.py` using command `inspectdb` from existing database in mysql. It has a model as below :

```
class Participationdata(models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey('Volunteer', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='UserId')  # Field name made lowercase.
    eventid = models.ForeignKey('Events', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='EventId')  # Field name made lowercase.
    ptrflag = models.IntegerField(db_column='PtrFlag', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'ParticipationData'
        unique_together = (('userid', 'eventid'),)
```

I have inserted the data into database using this model successfully. But while selecting data it is showing the error like :

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'Participationdata.id' in 'field list'")
```

How should I resolve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["unknown column X.id" error in django using existing DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192409/unknown-column-x-id-error-in-django-using-existing-db)

Comment: There's no primary key.

Comment: In database I have defined composite key as 'primary key(userid,eventid)'. so I am confused what should I do now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `id` field in `Participationdate` table?

Comment: No, I don't. These models are created from existing database using `inspectdb`

Comment: When You don't set primary key manually, Django automatically creates `id` field. You cannot explicitly set composite key - `unique_together` is some kind of trick. The error appears on selecting(also on other operations too) due to column `id` doesn't exist in database. but Django thinks that exists. You should consider use raw SQL queries and select only on columns that exists `userid`,`eventid`,`ptrflag`.

Comment: Use of raw sql is giving error `django.db.models.query_utils.InvalidQuery: Raw query must include the primary key
`

Comment: I wrongly said - you need to execute SQL code raw: not by using `SomeModel.objects.raw("SOME SQL CODE")`, but use `cursor`, e.g. `cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table')`

Comment: I resolved this by using `("Select UserId as id from ParticipationData" )`

Answer (score 4):

Usually you would set `primary_key = True` on your `eventid` field, so Django uses it as a default `id`. Look at the answer in [Custom id field in Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109940/custom-id-field-in-django-model)

But it is a `ForeignKeyField`, so you have to add id column to your database and model. You can remove `managed = False` (default is `True`) and then:

1. Create migrations for the model and `migrate --fake-initial` (since you have table already, see more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake-initial )
2. Add `AutoField id` to your model
3. Run `makemigrations` and `migrate` as usual.

That way django uses your already-existing table, but you can modify it via models.

Comment: Can I store multiple eventid by using primary key = true in this field ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it's ForeignKey. Then you should add id field to the model/db. Editing answer now...

Comment: Is there any way to do this without adding id field ?

Comment: Probably not. See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864283/django-models-and-primary-foreign-key-relationships

Answer (score 0):

I solve this error when I add `primary_key=True` to my id, because Django need a primary key. In my code, I add the primary key in my View id, because the `inspectdb` don't get the key from the database view

```
class ViewRespuestaEncuestas(models.Model):
    id_encuesta = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    encuesta = models.CharField(max_length=45, db_collation='utf8_general_ci')
    id_usuario = models.IntegerField()
    nombre_usuario = models.CharField(
        max_length=40, db_collation='utf8_general_ci', blank=True, null=True)
    id_pregunta = models.IntegerField()
    pregunta = models.TextField(db_collation='utf8_general_ci')
    id_respuesta = models.IntegerField()
    respuesta = models.CharField(max_length=60, db_collation='utf8_general_ci')
    valor = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False  # Created from a view. Don't remove.
        db_table = 'view_respuesta_encuestas'
```